# How to get the value of title image and content in ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How to display the data title, image and content?

Here's the code:

***view.php***

```
 $id = $_REQUEST['edit_literature_id'];
        $literature = $_REQUEST['literatureID'];
        $module = $_REQUEST['edit_moduleId'];

        if (isset($id)) {
            $dataArr = array();
            $responseArr = array();
            
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $literature WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
            
            if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $data['title'] = $row['title'];
                    $data['name'] = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['name']);
                    $data['content'] = $row['content'];

                        array_push($dataArr, $data);
                    }
                    echo  json_encode($dataArr);
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
            } else {
                echo "No Record";
            }
        }
```

***index.php***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btnModalUpdate', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                rowId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                moduleData = $(this).attr('data-module');
                literatureData = $(this).attr('data-literature');
                $('#edit_id').val(rowId);
                $('#edit_module').val(moduleData);
                $('#edit_literature').val(literatureData);
                $('#edit_imageId').val(rowId);
                $('#update').val('update');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../../crud/read/view.php',
                    data: $('#modalFormUpdate').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data)
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to get the title, image and content.
How to get the value of title, image and content?

How to call the "title", "name" and "content" from the php?

[image]
`console.log('DATA: ' + data);`

Comment: Your data is in json, and it's an array. So doing `console.log(data[0].title)` should give you the title?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use while loop for result. Also remove extra `$dataArr` and `$responseArr`

Update your code to:

in  view.php

```
$id = $_REQUEST['edit_literature_id'];
    $literature = $_REQUEST['literatureID'];
    $module = $_REQUEST['edit_moduleId'];

    if (isset($id)) {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $literature WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
      if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
         if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $data['title'] = $row['title'];
            $data['name'] = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['name']);
            $data['content'] = $row['content'];
            echo  json_encode($data); exit;
            }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
      $data['error'] = "No Record";
      echo  json_encode($data); exit;
```

Index.php

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#btnModalUpdate', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                rowId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                moduleData = $(this).attr('data-module');
                literatureData = $(this).attr('data-literature');
                $('#edit_id').val(rowId);
                $('#edit_module').val(moduleData);
                $('#edit_literature').val(literatureData);
                $('#edit_imageId').val(rowId);
                $('#update').val('update');
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../../crud/read/view.php',
                    data: $('#modalFormUpdate').serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                        var title = response.title;
                        var name = response.name;
                        var content = response.content;

                         alert(title);
                         alert(name);
                         alert(content);
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

After taking data from jQuery side, you can set value in html side using id or class attribute in jQuery.

Comment: the data is undefined

Comment: title, name and content value is undefined

Comment: try to see data in console using console.log(data); and share screen shot.

Comment: thank you sir for helping me to solved my problem. appreciated your help.

Comment: do I need to remove the ```dataType: 'json'```, cause I'm having a error: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (literature.php:646)```

Comment: Please don't suggest SQL injection vulnerable code.

Comment: @Dharman i didnt make sql query, i just update iverson`s code with fix and question is not about sql injection prevention. he should do it own him self . :)

Comment: No, you should fix all the problems with the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

How your ajax receiving .php file *should look*:

```
$validLiteratureIds = ['yourTable1', 'yourTable2']; 
if (!isset($_GET['edit_literature_id'], $_GET['literatureID']) || !in_array($_GET['literatureID'], $validLiteratureIds)) {
    $response = ['error' => 'Missing/Invalid Data Submitted'];
} else {
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbname');
    $sql = "SELECT title, name, content
            FROM `{$_GET['literatureID']}`
            WHERE `id` = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET['edit_literature_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($title, $name, $content);
    if (!$stmt->fetch()) {
        $response = ['error' => 'No Record'];
    } else {
        $response = [
            'title'=> $title,
            'name' => 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($name),
            'content' => $content
        ];
    }
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Important practices:

- Validate the user input so that only qualifying submissions have the privilege of accessing your database.
- Write the failure outcomes before success outcomes consistently throughout your project, this will make your scripts easier to read/follow.
- Always use prepared statements and bind user-supplied data to placeholders into your query for stability/security.
- The tablename cannot be bound like the `id` value; it must be written directly into your sql string -- this is why it is critical that you validate the value against a whitelist array of literature ids.
- There is no need to declare new variables to receive the `$_GET` values; just access the values directly from the superglobal array.
- I am going to assume that your `id` is a primary/unique key in your table(s), so you don't need to loop over your result set.  Attempt to fetch one row -- it will either contain data or the result set was empty.
- Call `json_encode()` only once and at the end of your script.
- It is not worth clearing any results or closing a prepared statement or a connection, because those tasks are automatically done when the script execution is finished anyhow -- avoid the script bloat.

As for your jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#btnModalUpdate', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../../crud/read/view.php',
            data: $('#modalFormUpdate').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                   console.log(response.error);
                } else {
                   console.log(response.title, response.name, response.content);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

- I've trim away all of the irrelevant lines
- changed POST to GET -- because you are merely reading data from the database, not writing
- `parseJSON()` is not necessary -- `response` is a ready-to-use object.
- I am checking for an `error` property in the response object so that the appropriate data is accessed.

Both scripts above are untested (and completely written from my phone).  If I have made any typos, please leave me a comment and I'll fix it up.